# Exception thrown: System.IO.FileNotFoundException in mscorlib.dll and Could not find file in path of IsolatedStorage

Tags: wpf, rdlc

When i try to open rdlc report in my application. It's crashed and throw **FileNotFoundException**.

```
Message: Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll 
Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\Users\MK\AppData\Local\IsolatedStorage\bcxmetoa.uo3\ubbnwekp.r2d\Publisher.hrvyd13ddpxak55x41ce0efyq30aahdz\AssemFiles\ReportPageTempFile-d34a01d1-c9dc-4da7-a988-53e8957d19de'.
```

After installing only **Microsoft Expression Encoder 4** , i have faced this problem. Before it's working properly in my machine. I need MS ExpressionEncoder software, to capture the WebCam image in my application. So not possible to uninstall MS ExpressionEncoder software in my machine. Any idea to resolve this problem.